# Run Batch File Manually after Deploy Phase Maven

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, maven-plugin

I'm using Maven's Tomacat plugin to deploy the WAR file to localhost server. I'm trying to run a .bat file after maven has deployed the war file using maven antrun plugin but the .bat file is not being exceuted.

POM file Snippet

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <exec executable="cmd.exe"
                                spawn="true">
                                <arg value="/c"/>
                                <arg value="C:\Users\Hp\workspace\test\run.bat"/>
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>      
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
             <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>APP A</server>
            <username>sample_username</username>
            <password>sample_password</password>
            <update>true</update>
            <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Bat file code

```
  echo "Hello World!!!"
```

Maven goals being used.

```
  clean install tomcat7:deploy -e
```

When I run the above maven command the WAR file gets successfully deployed to Localhost but the .bat file does not get executed as the Hello World does not get printed. Can't understand what I need to do to run the bat file using a maven goal and not by default.

Comment: The maven *deploy* is not connected to the plugin *tomcat7:deploy*. If you use the *install* you should put this in the pom execution.

Comment: I'm using the goal "tomcat7:deploy" to deploy the war file after install phase..so should the phase in ant-run plugin be deploy or install??

Comment: I think you should use *install*, as is the target you use with the command line: *mvn clean install...*. Change it and try again.

Comment: Tried that still nothing is happening?? Is there some other plugin which can do this task?

Comment: sorry I see now you should change the goal too. Always install.

Comment: Always install in pom file or the maven command??

Comment: the *<goal>run</goal>* to be *<goal>install</goal>*

Comment: tried that...got an error "Could not find goal 'install' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins"

Comment: Sorry, today I'm a bit confused today... holidays... *<goal>run</goal>* is ok on plugin antrun. If changing the phase don't work the only way is by calling it directly in your command line: *mvn clean install antrun:run ...*